What is the number ways to count tuples whose sum is zero?
Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of order $q$, where $q$ is a prime power. Then to count number of i-tuples of the form $(a_1,a_2,....,a_i)$ such that all $a_1,a_2,..,a_i$ are non-zero and $a_1+a_2+..+a_i=0$.
I tried by counting $i-1$-tuples such that $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{i-1})$ such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{i-1}\neq 0$ but I could not determine this number either.

For convenience, write $\vec{\mathbf a}=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, and let $V\subset \mathbb F_q^n$ be the set of vectors $\vec{\mathbf a}$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_n=0$. By inclusion-exclusion, we hope to compute:
$$q^{n-1}-n\cdot \#\{\vec{\mathbf a}\in V:a_1=0\}+{n\choose 2}\cdot\#\{\vec{\mathbf a}\in V:a_1,a_2=0\}-\cdots,$$
which equals, by the binomial theorem,
$$
\begin{align*}q^{n-1}-nq^{n-2}+{n\choose 2}q^{n-3}-\cdots&=\frac{(q-1)^n-(-1)^{n-1}(q-1)}q\\
&=(q-1)\frac{(q-1)^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}}q.
\end{align*}$$

I assume you forgot to add $a_i \neq 0$?

Let $F(n)$ be the number of never zero lists of length $n$ which do not sum to $0$.
$$F(0)=0$$
$$F(1)=q-1$$
$$F(n)=(q-2)F(n-1)+(q-1)F(n-2)$$
The first term accounts for the case that the sum to $n-1$ is nonzero, the second term accounts for the case where the sum to $n-1$ is zero.
Your sequence is the rightwards shift of this sequence: for $n$ nonzero elements to sum to $0$ means exactly that the first $n-1$ of them summed to something nonzero, and the last element is the (unique) additive inverse of that.
This is a linear recursion of degree $2$. Explicit formulas are not so hard to derive. It will be a sum of two geometric sequences, whose ratios are the roots of $x^2 -(q-2)x-(q-1)$ if those roots are different. It turns out, the roots are $-1$ and $q-1$, so an explicit formula is:
$$\frac{q-1}{q}((q-1)^n-(-1)^n)$$
Note that all we used was the group structure of the field (and not even that it has prime power order or that it was abelian). Thus this recursion generalizes to arbitrary groups.

Here is an algebraic way to attack this problem. These methods are by no means necessary, but they give a little peak into how these sorts of questions can be dealt with in algebraic geometry.
Write $q=p^r$ and $G=\mathbb{F}_q^\times$. Let $\chi:\mathbb{F}_q\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be the multiplicative character given by $$\chi(a)=\xi^{\text{Tr}(a)}$$ where $\xi$ is a fixed primitive $p$th root of unity and $\text{Tr}:\mathbb{F}_q\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_p$ is the trace of the linear map $x\mapsto ax$, i.e. $$\text{Tr}(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}a^{p^k}$$ You should verify that $\text{Tr}$ is indeed linear (and has image in $\mathbb{F}_p$) so that $\chi$ is a group homomorphism $(\mathbb{F}_q,+)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$. It is a simple exercise to show $$\sum_{x\in G}\chi(xu)=\begin{cases}q-1 & u=0\\ -1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Then, given a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, it follows that $$\sum_{y\in G}\sum_{x\in G^{\ n}}\chi(yf(x))=(q-1)|V|-|G^n-V| = q|V|-(q-1)^n\tag{*}$$
where $V$ is the set of zeroes of $f$ in $G^n$. In our case, $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1+\ldots+x_n$, so we have $$\sum_{y\in G}\sum_{x\in G^{\ n}}\chi(y(x_1+\ldots,x_n))=\sum_{y\in G}\left(\sum_{x\in G}\chi(yx)\right)^n=\sum_{y\in G}(-1)^n=(q-1)(-1)^n$$ Then by $(*)$, we get $$|V|=\frac{(q-1)^n+(q-1)(-1)^n}{q}$$
